# Are there historical wars in which both sides commited genocide on each other?

Tags: genocide

Historically, genocides are often associated with a strong power asymmetry.  For example, the Jews in the Holocaust, the Romani in the Porajmos, the Ukrainians in the Holodomor, the Armenians in the Armenian genocide, or the Herero/Namaqua in the Herero/Namaqua genocide ([or others](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_genocides)) had little to no power to defend themselves, least of all to commit "revenge" genocide against the population from which their perpetrators came.  In World War II and the war in former Yugoslavia, war crimes were committed by multiple parties.  However, in WW II, only Nazi war crimes are universally seen as genocide, and in former Yugoslavia only the Srebrenica Massacre appears to meet that bar.

According to Wikipedia, the [flight and expulsion of Germans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flight_and_expulsion_of_Germans_(1944%E2%80%931950)) in the aftermath of WW II in Europe is described by many historians as *ethnic cleansing*, but that applying the term *genocide* is controversial.  Similarly, there appears to be no consensus whether [Soviet war crimes against Germans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soviet_war_crimes#Germany) amount to genocide.

Is this a near-universal pattern, or are there historical wars/conflicts where both sides committed genocide, according to the [UN definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genocide_Convention) (including retroactively)?

Comment: I suspect that there are been many conflicts where each side attempted genocide against the other.

Comment: I added another example to my answer, you might be interested.

Answer (score 13):

[Taiping Rebellion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taiping_Rebellion#Total_war)

> In every area which they captured, the Taiping immediately exterminated the entire Manchu population. In the province of Hunan one Qing loyalist who observed the genocidal massacres which the Taiping forces committed against the Manchus wrote that the "pitiful Manchus"—men, women and children—were executed by the Taiping forces. The Taiping rebels were seen chanting while slaughtering the Manchus in Hefei. After capturing Nanjing, Taiping forces killed about 40,000 Manchu civilians. On 27 October 1853, they crossed the Yellow River in Cangzhou and murdered 10,000 Manchus.
>
> Since the rebellion began in Guangxi, Qing forces allowed no rebels speaking its dialect to surrender. Reportedly in the province of Guangdong, it is written that one million were executed because after the collapse of the Taiping Heavenly Kingdom, the Qing dynasty launched waves of massacres against the Hakkas, that at their height killed up to 30,000 each day. These policies of mass murder of civilians occurred elsewhere in China, including Anhui and Nanjing. This resulted in a massive civilian flight and death toll with some 600 towns destroyed and other bloody policies resulting.

Also [Israel vs. Arab League, 1948](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Killings_and_massacres_during_the_1948_Palestine_war)

> According to Benny Morris the Yishuv (or later Israeli) soldiers killed roughly 800 Arab civilians and prisoners of war in 24 massacres. Aryeh Yizthaki list 10 major massacres with more than 50 victims each. Palestinian researcher Salman Abu-Sitta lists 33 massacres, half of them occurring during the civil war period. Saleh Abdel Jawad lists 68 villages where acts of indiscriminate killing of prisoners, and civilians took place, where no threat was posed to Yishuv or Israeli soldiers.
>
> The main massacres and attacks against Jewish civilians were the Haifa Oil Refinery massacre where 39 Jews were killed by Arab workers after Irgun members had thrown a bomb into the crowd and the Kfar Etzion massacre where around 120-150 residents and defenders were killed by Arab irregulars, according to some accounts with the participation of Arab Legion soldiers. The Hadassah medical convoy massacre, with 80 deaths, included the mass killing of medical personnel by Arabs.

Comment: That's all really sad to read.